# Why are certain values written via [ngModel] not updating in the UI?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am seeing inconsistent behavior where the UI does not update correctly for certain values written to a field bound to `[ngModel]`.

My template:

```
<input
  type="number"
  [ngModel]="displayValue"
  (ngModelChange)="updateValue($event)"
/>
```

TS file:

```
export class HelloComponent {
  displayValue = 0;

  public updateValue(displayValue: number) {
    const validatedValue = this.constrainValue(displayValue);
    this.displayValue = validatedValue;
  }

  private constrainValue(value: number) {
    return (value > 100) ? 100 : value;
  }
}
```

- If I enter a 3 digit number over `100` (ie: `230`), `constrainValue` adjusts it to `100` and they UI updates as expected.
- If I enter a 6 digit number (ie: `23456`), `constrainValue` adjusts it to `100` **but the UI only updates the first 3 numbers** so I get `10056`.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-eleb1u?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: Your stackblitz has nothing to do with your code.

Comment: Maybe this `[ngModel]` should be this `[(ngModel)]`?

Comment: wrapping `this.displayValue = validatedValue;` with `setTimeout` works.

Comment: I am guessing UI change detection does not run in the middle of a `ngModelChange` event. When `this.displayValue` is already `100`, then you type `1005` in the text field, even you have used `[(ngModel)]` correctly, `this.displayValue` is `1005` when `updateValue` called, but it is set back to `100` immediately before `updateValue` return. So the change detection engine can only see `this.displayValue` equals to `100` before and after the `ngModelChange` event, so no UI refresh is done.

Comment: One solution is to ensure the change detection engine have `1005` detected before setting it to `100` again. This can be achieved by wrapping `this.displayValue = validatedValue` with `setTimeout(()=>{},0)`, delaying the assignment by one tick.  Another solution is to use `(change)` and `(keydown)` events instead of `(ngModelChange)`

Comment: @RickyMo sorry, forgot to click save - the stackblitz is now working.

Comment: @R.Richards I am intentionally not using 2 way binding. If I did I would have the entered value (which could be > 100) written straight back to `displayValue` - I want to constrain it first.

Comment: @RickyMo you are pretty much on the mark. Essentially `this.displayValue` was `100` before and is assigned `100` again, therefore no change detection initiated and therefore the control is not updated. Although note that `[ngModel]` is also 'correct' if you want one way binding (which I do). If you want to write up an answer I'll accept it, otherwise I will self-answer. Thanks

Comment: However the `setTimeout` does not seem to resolve it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-eleb1u?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: `setTimeout` resolves it only when you use `[(ngModel)]`, because you need `1005` to be written to `displayValue` before you update it with `100` so that there is a "change". If you use `[ngModel]`, `displayValue` always stays at `100` so even `setTimeout` doesn't help. Alternatively you may manually assign some value (e.g. `undefined`) to it before `setTimeout` before assigning `100` to it in `setTimeout`. The point is to make sure the is a "change" **AFTER** `ngModelChange` event.